# Understanding an algorithm solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wanted to solve the problem here on my own: [To find the longest substring with equal sum in left and right in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469407/to-find-the-longest-substring-with-equal-sum-in-left-and-right-in-c)

The code is here

```
int getEqualSumSubstring(string s) {
    int i=0,j=i,foundLength=0;
    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<s.length();j++)
        {
            int temp = j-i+1;

            if(temp%2==0)
            {
                int leftSum=0,rightSum=0;
                string tempString=s.substr(i,temp);
                // printf("%d ",tempString.length());
                for(int k=0;k<temp/2;k++)
                {
                    leftSum=leftSum+tempString[k]-48;
                    rightSum=rightSum+tempString[k+(temp/2)]-48;
                }
                if((leftSum==rightSum)&&(leftSum!=0))
                    if(tempString.length()>foundLength)
                    foundLength=tempString.length(); 
            }
        }
    }
    return(foundLength);
}
```

I wanted to know how the calculation of temp = i+j-1 is done ? how on paper or by examples he could get that equation. I tried a lot but I couldn't get it.

Comment: *"I wanted to know how the calculation of temp = i+j-1 is done ?"* Presumably you mean you want to know how the programmer chose this calculation? Because *"how [it] is done"* is by adding `i` and `j`, subtracting one and assigning the result to `temp`.

Comment: what If I want the second loop to go from i+1 instead of i. How that changes the calculations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the length of the substring, where i and j are left and right bounds of the substring respectively. If we have a segment on the line from x to y, x < y, then it's length is y - x. As we have here a discrete object, the length can vary by 1 or 2. Here, as we took closed bounds, the length of the substring both starting and ending in the position i will be 1 = i - i + 1, so the formula should be j - i + 1.

Comment: would you please give a pictorial illustration :). I'm noob.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l518cjht6z8xapn/snapshot.png
Is such a visual description clear?