# Split the numeric string and Find sum

Tags: c#, algorithm, language-agnostic

How do I write a method, which takes a single argument. The single argument is a string **s**, which contains only non-zero digits.

This function should print the length of longest contiguous substring of s, such that the length of the substring is **2*N** digits (maximum length of the string is 49) and the sum of the leftmost N digits is equal to the sum of the rightmost N digits.If there is no such string, your function should print 0

I am learner to c#. I saw this puzzle and failed to do.

Sample Input: 123231 and Expected Output is 6

Explanation:

1 + 2 + 3 = 2 + 3 + 1. 
The length of the longest substring = 6 where the sum of 1st half = 2nd half

Sample Input#2 : 986561517416921217551395112859219257312 Output is 36

```
static int myMethod(string s) {

 var input = "123231";
 bool expected = 
 new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[1-9]+$").IsMatch(input);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `c#`, `java` & `asp.net`, all 3 together? + what have you tried till now?

Comment: It's great that you're learning, please format your calculations. Also, what approaches have you tried? Where did they fail?

Comment: @R.J Any language is accepted. Just a logic

Comment: Is it a homework question?

Comment: IMHO, logic is language **independent**.

Comment: is this from a projecteuler.net? If so, what task is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using LINQ alot, hopefully that helps you. The "trick" is that you must check both the new versions of the whole string, ie lop of first int as well as last in. This question has been asked before here at SO though, but as a c++ question. It looks a lot nicer in C# :)

```
int GetSumString(string s)
{
  // Convert everything to int[], easier that way in .NET
  var numbersOrg = s.Select(t => int.Parse(t.ToString())).ToArray();

  // Its possible to optimize by using ienumerable and lazy evaluation i guess, but I'm lazy :)
  var queue = new Queue<int[]>();
  queue.Enqueue(numbersOrg);

  while (queue.Any())
  {
      var numbers = queue.Dequeue();   

      var firstHalf = numbers.Take(numbers.Length / 2).Sum();
      var secondHalf = numbers.Skip(numbers.Length / 2).Sum();
      // It must be of even length (% 2) and the sum of the first half must be equal to the last half.
      if (numbers.Length % 2 == 0 && firstHalf == secondHalf)
          return numbers.Length;

      // Console.WriteLine("tried: " + string.Join("", numbers) + " gave (" + firstHalf + "," + secondHalf + ")");
      // Only enqueue when we have something left in the array
      if (numbers.Length > 1)
      {
          queue.Enqueue(numbers.Take(numbers.Length - 1).ToArray());
          queue.Enqueue(numbers.Skip(1).ToArray());
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The solution is as such that is does the checks in correct order, ie the first "solution" is garanteed to be the longest solution.

Comment: @BadDeveloper In .NET 1.0? Is there a reason for this? Have a look at this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469407/to-find-the-longest-substring-with-equal-sum-in-left-and-right-in-c since that one is closer to .NET 1.0 than my answer.

Comment: @BadDeveloper you have been asked to do this with `.net 1.0`? Why is that? *asking just of the interest*

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the possible combinations. Example for the `123231` string:

```
1=2         -> fail
1+2=3+2     -> fail
1+2+3=2+3+1 -> len=6, longest so far
2=3         -> fail
2+3=2+3     -> len=4, not longer
3=2         -> fail
3+2=3+1     -> fail
2=3         -> fail
3=1         -> fail
```

Something like this:

```
int longest = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
  for (j = longest + 1; i + j * 2 <= str.Length; j++) {
    if (sum(str, i, j) == sum(str, i + j, j)) {
      longest = j;
    }
  }
}

int sum(string str, int offset, int len) {
  int s = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) s += (int)(str[offset + i] - '0');
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me to loop your logic with c#. :(

Comment: It gives the output 2 and not 6 :(

Comment: @BadDeveloper: That's why i wrote "something like this" :). It should be `<=` instead of `<` in the condition for the inner loop.